# how to build the index for data in the database for lucene search

Tags: asp.net, lucene, lucene.net

We want to make a full text search for the data in our database,and we want to use the Lucene.net to make this.

In java ,I can use the hibernate-search to build index and search,but in .net I wonder if there is any idea to implement it?

If no existed tool,how to build the index manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the .NET version of hibernate (NHibernate), which also has the Search extension.
http://ayende.com/blog/3992/nhibernate-search

Comment: we just want to use the full text search,if use the nHibernate we have to change all of our exist codes.